# Ubuntu: After uninstalling package, it is still there

Tags: ubuntu, uninstallation

I uninstalled gem. Now if I give in the command:

```
sudo apt-get remove gem
```

It returns:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'gem' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 41 not upgraded
```

So I assume it is successfully uninstalled. However, if I ask the version, it still works:

```
gem --version
```

It returns:

```
2.5.2.1
```

Also, if I write "ge" and then hit the tab, I get the auto-completion for gem.
Why is this? And what is the "41 not upgraded" ? Thank you!

Comment: did you install gem using the apt-get method or was it preinstalled? Also what is your Ubuntu version?

Comment: I'm not sure it was preinstalled. Im on Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I removed gem in my Ubuntu 18.04, this should also work on previous Ubuntus:

```
sudo apt-get purge ruby
```

If I am not wrong gem is a part of Ruby. As a regular Python user I am not entirely sure about gem being part of Ruby, but the above command certainly removed gem from my Ubuntu.

```
sudo apt-get purge ruby*
```

This command will remove grub! so be careful. The two commands differ.

Answer (score 1):

This could happen if you installed the package manually (not through the package manager). In this case the package manager (apt-get) might not be aware of the package and its location and so not think that it is installed. The auto-complete functionality in terminal is simply based on it being in the system path ($PATH).

Run `which gem` in order to find where the executable is installed.

Try running `apt-get update` followed by `apt-get upgrade` to get more information about the 'not upgraded' packages.

Comment: thank you, it helped to find how to remove gem from the auto-complete, I deleted the /HOME/.gem folder and now it is gone both from the auto-complete and the --version returns nothing. The gem disappeared by uninstalling ruby, so I have to accept that one.

Answer (score 0):

for getting package name write following command

> $ dpkg --get-selections | grep -v deinstall | grep software_name | awk '{ print $1 }'

for remove package

> $ sudo apt-get purge package_name